# (When) Does order matter in counting solutions?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on a problem,

> How many solutions are there of the equation $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=37,$$ such that $y_1>1,\;y_2>2,\;y_3>3,\;y_4>4$?

My reasoning so far is

> Let $0<x_i=y_i-i$; then the number of solutions to the given equation is the same as the number of solutions to the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=27,$$ namely $$\binom{27-1}{4-1}=\binom{26}{3}=\frac{26\times25\times24}{3\times2}=2600.$$

But I'm wondering if the ordering of the $y$ inequalities matters in some way I haven't taken into account. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: No problem: the ordering matters but you *did* take it into account in your change of unknowns.

Comment: @AnneBauval That's what I was hoping. I just wondered if that was "allowed" and sufficient.